# How to run HTML, CSS and JavaScript codes in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sublimetext3, sublimetext

With using Ctrl+B I see this error:
No Build System.
What should I do to run my codes and What packages Should I install?

Answer (score 7):

You can set up Chrome as a build system in Sublime:

1. Go to **Tools** -> **Build System**
2. Choose **New Build System**. This should open up a new file.
3. Delete everything in that file, and copy the following command in (where `PATH_TO_CHROME` is replaced by the path to Chrome on your system):

   ```
   {
       "cmd":["PATH_TO_CHROME","$file"]
   }
   ```
4. Save the file as `Chrome.sublime-build`
5. Close Sublime, and then open it again
6. If you go to **Tools** -> **Build System** now, you should now see **Chrome** as an option. Select it.
7. Now, whenever you hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, it will open your HTML in Chrome.

Answer (score -2):

You can just open your HTML file in a browser. Locate the HTML file on your computer, right click, open with { whatever browser you use }.